# How do I create a .tpl file for a panel pane?

Tags: 7, panels

So, I want to add some HTML to surround the output of a Panel pane. I know the existing pane is rendered with:

`panels-pane--entity-field-extra.tpl.php`

If I edit this file, of course, every pane using it will show the changes.

If I create a new .tpl, say `panels-pane--entity-field-top.tpl.php` how do I apply it to a particular pane?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer [Documentation on Panels Pane template](https://www.drupal.org/node/1678810), which provides details on how to define a template for Panels Pane. If you want to add your own template name you can also do that by implementing `template_preprocess_panels_pane` in your theme or module file. Example for same is also available on documentation page.